# Using React withRouter for Class Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

For the functional component, I have used withRouter for redirect to another component like below:

```
    const buttonClick = (history) => {
      history.push('/spot');
    };
   const Topleft = withRouter(({history}) => {
     return (  );
   });

   export default Topleft;
```

I want to does exactly the same thing for the class component.
  Like Below:

```
class TopLeft component {
 render(){
   return()
  }
}

 export default Topleft;
```

How can I do that?
Can anyone please help.

Comment: you can get history or location object from class component props. Just use HOC and wrap `Topleft`: `export default withRouter(Topleft);`

Comment: export default withRouter(Topleft) will work

Comment: @demkovych How to pass history in that case?

Comment: @MehadiHassan this.props.history will work then

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to the history object's properties and the closest 's match via the withRouter higher-order component.

```
const { match, location, history } = this.props;
...
export default withRouter(Topleft);
```